Wifi becomes slow after sleep
I am having an issue with my Windows 11 laptop where after some time in sleep mode or after a reboot the internet over WIFI becomes very slow (I am talking emails taking 5 minutes to load and speedtest failing).
I initially attributed this to my router, but since then I have tried another one to no avail. Moreover, this issue never happens on my phone or any other device for that matter. Also, there are no settings on the router that will set any specific rules for this laptop.
Interestingly, a fix that I found to be 100% working is to forget the network and connect again (regular reconnect has no effect). Also, In my router menu I have found that when the laptop is in "slow mode" the Mbit/s metric would fluctuate from 2 to 30, but when I do the fix it shows a constant value like so:

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting, but since it seems to be an issue with my laptop in particular, maybe it is the fact that my WIFI card is a newer WIFI6 compatible one (intel AX200 160Mhz) and the router is rather old 2.4Ghz only model (the other router I tried is just as old). The driver is up to date and I have even tried reinstalling it, but it didn't help.

Others also have the issue that WiFi does not reconnect, or behaves erratically, after Sleep or Hibernation. Two workarounds to use are as follows; either or both may be needed.

Use a Windows batch file to reset and renew network connections:


Copy the following and paste into a text document:
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
arp -d *
nbtstat -R
nbtstat -RR
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns

Save the file with extension .bat, e.g. resetnet.bat.

Make a shortcut to that file.

Right-click the shortcut, and in Properties, Advanced, set Run as administrator, and set a keyboard shortcut, if you wish.



Use a tool such as Nirsoft's WiFiInfoView to select the optimal connection. For example, there might be 2.4, 5 and 6 GHz access points with same name, but different BSSID. Test each with that tool to see which has best signal quality.
Sometimes theoretically faster higher bands may be slower, because higher frequencies penetrate some materials less effectively. After using the tool to switch access points, try an internet speed test, such as SpeedTest.net.

Once that is established, use the app to make a desktop shortcut to the preferred access point. Set a keyboard shortcut, if you wish. This shortcut does not need to be run as Administrator.


Admittedly, these are workarounds, and do not solve the basic underlying cause in Windows. It should not be necessary to have to run an app after waking from Sleep or Hibernation. sigh

Since posting this I have found a solution: I just disabled the 40MHz option in the router settings (it was set to Automatic 20/40) since I saw that my laptop is the only device using it and the speed will be more than covered by 20MHz in my case. For several days I have no issues whatsoever.
